# Package is accessible from more than one module in JDK 11 Module system

Tags: java, struts2, java-11, java-module, module-info

We are making use of Zulu JDK 11 and we are facing issue The package com.sample.test is accessible from more than one module: test1.module, test2.sample.

Below is the git url for sample project and screenshot for your reference.

https://github.com/kkvaranasi88/test1.git

Comment: where is the screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to rename the package in your second module `tes-2` to say `com.sample.another.test` and then update your module description to

```
module test2.sample {
    exports com.sample.another.test;
    requires transitive test1.module;
}
```

and things shall work fine.

Having said that, the cause for failure is that no two modules should export the *same `package`* such that they are both resolved in the module layer as s conflict.

Comment: This will work with user defined packages. But what about framework ones. Suppose if I am working on application on struts 2 and I am making use of struts2-core.jar, struts2-junit-pulugin.jar which shares the common package name org.apache.struts2. Please find theStruts2Example in the git url https://github.com/kkvaranasi88/Test which doesn't work on JDK11 or even from JDK 9 onwards. Even I have opened the jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-5032?filter=-8