# How to make a package not accessible from a module (i.e. how to remove a package from a module?)

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system

## Short Version

What file do i have to delete from what folder to stop the error:

> The package %s is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, %s

## Long Version

When trying to build a Java web-site, i am getting the error:

> The package %s is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, %s

For example:

[image]

- `The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module: \<unnamed\>, java.xml`
- `The package javax.xml.parsers is accessible from more than one module: \<unnamed\>, java.xml`
- `The package netscape.javascript is accessible from more than one module: \<unnamed\>, jdk.jsobject`
- `The package org.xml.sax is accessible from more than one module: \<unnamed\>, java.xml`

Now:

- I don't know what a module is
- and i don't know what a package is

But i do get get the sense that i need to delete a file (maybe a `.jar` file), or i need to edit a configuration file to remove a line, or i need to delete files elsewhere on my computer, or i need to delete environment variables.

- i don't know what file to delete
- i don't know what `.jar` file to delete
- i don't know what text file to edit
- i don't know what configuration file to edit
- i don't know what line in what text file to add, edit, or remove

So, how do i:

> Make package %s ***not*** accessible from more than one module

---

Apparently it is an bug added with Java 9 and the [**Java Platform Module System (JPMS)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System), and it is not anything to do with Eclipse, NetBeans, or any IDE. It is a rule that was always there, but only Java 9 started enforcing it.

- Some [say you can disable the JPMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571046/eclipse-is-confused-by-imports-accessible-from-more-than-one-module) by deleting `module-info.java`
- Others insist that you cannot disable JPMS at all after Java 8, and you just have to live on Java 8
- Some have said that if you delete `module-info.java` it will get re-created

I don't have a `module-info.java` file anywhere in the folder or subfolders of the project

- Others suggest it is an issue with `classpath`, or `modulepath`

Although i don't have a classpath or modulepath set:

```
>echo %classpath%
%classpath%

>echo %modulepath%
%modulepath%

>echo %java_home%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1
```

IDE: [Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72793527/cannot-add-glassfish-server-to-netbeans-ide-14)

### Project structure

The web-site is make up of a structure of files and folders. Some are probably there by convention, some are probably there by rule, and some may have been a dumping ground for extra stuff. I don't know which is which:

- .vscode
- build
- conf
- dist
- JMeter
- LibrarySourceCode
- <strike>nbproject</strike> *(deleted in an attempt to fix the issue)*
- sql
- src
- WebRoot

  - applets
  - META-INF
  - WEB-INF

    - classes
    - lib

      - activation.jar
      - cglib-full-2.0.2.jar
      - commons-beanutils.jar
      - commons-codec-1.3.jar
      - commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
      - commons-collections4-4.4.jar
      - commons-compress-1.20.jar
      - commons-dbcp-1.2.1.jar
      - commons-digester.jar
      - commons-fileupload.jar
      - commons-lang-1.0.1.jar
      - commons-logging-1.2.jar
      - commons-math3-3.6.1.jar
      - commons-pool-1.2.jar
      - commons-validator.jar
      - curvesapi-1.06.jar
      - dom.jar
      - dom4j-1.4.jar
      - ehcache-0.9.jar
      - hibernate2.jar
      - itext-1.4.jar
      - jakarta-oro.jar
      - jaxen-full.jar
      - jaxp-api.jar
      - jmf.jar
      - jstl.jar
      - jta.jar
      - log4j-1.2-api-2.17.1.jar
      - log4j-api-2.17.1.jar
      - log4j-core-2.17.1.jar
      - log4j-jcl-2.17.1.jar
      - mail.jar
      - odmg-3.0.jar
      - ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar
      - plugin.jar
      - poi-3.9-20121203.jar
      - poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar
      - poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar
      - sax.jar
      - saxpath.jar
      - sessionmon.jar
      - sqljdbc41.jar
      - standard.jar
      - struts.jar
      - xalan.jar
      - xercesImpl.jar
      - xml-apis.jar
      - xmlbeans-3.0.1.jar
      - xmlbeans-4.0.0.jar
      - xmlbeans-5.0.3.jar
    - tags
- <strike>build.xml</strike> *(deleted in an attempt to fix the issue)*

### Research Effort

> That's a restriction by the Java Platform Module System (JPMS), not by Eclipse (so don't shoot the messenger). If you delete the file module-info.java in your default package (which disables JPMS) it should work with Java 9 or higher.

- [Eclipse is confused by imports ("accessible from more than one module")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571046/eclipse-is-confused-by-imports-accessible-from-more-than-one-module)
- [Package accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55902512/package-accessible-from-more-than-one-module-unnamed)
- [The package org.xml.sax is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72171466/the-package-org-xml-sax-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module-unnamed-java)
- [The package javax.xml.namespace is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml in eclipse webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61551300/the-package-javax-xml-namespace-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module-unname)
- [The package is accessible from more than one module (Error fix for using SAX in Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67227759/the-package-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module-error-fix-for-using-sax-in)
- [The package java.util is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.base while adding 'android.jar' in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63792162/the-package-java-util-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module-unnamed-java-b)
- [The package java.util is accessible from more than one module: error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59053049/the-package-java-util-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module-error)
- [Eclipse error The package javax.xml.datatype is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml - split packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69760969/eclipse-error-the-package-javax-xml-datatype-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-mo)
- [The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57286825/the-package-org-w3c-dom-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module-unnamed-java)
- [The package javax.xml.stream is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63938809/the-package-javax-xml-stream-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module-unnamed)
- [Error importing org packages - accessible from more than one module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69308625/error-importing-org-packages-accessible-from-more-than-one-module)
- [Eclipse RCP , The packagexxx is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70660455/eclipse-rcp-the-packagexxx-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module-unnamed)
- [Package is accessible from more than one module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57551269/package-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module)
- [The package javax.xml.namespace is accessible from more than one module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59935009/the-package-javax-xml-namespace-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module)
- [Package accessible from more than one module in Eclipse RCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60802975/package-accessible-from-more-than-one-module-in-eclipse-rcp)
- [The package org.json is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, org.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68832650/the-package-org-json-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module-unnamed-org-jso)
- [Java 11 migration: Package is accessible from more than one module issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68839894/java-11-migration-package-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module-issue)
- [VSCode: The package is accessible from more than one module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61278108/vscode-the-package-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module)
- [The package *** is accessible from more than one module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60703832/the-package-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module)
- [The package javax.xml.transform is accesible from more than one module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66638659/the-package-javax-xml-transform-is-accesible-from-more-than-one-module)
- [The package is accessible from more than one module problem under VSCode only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58873562/the-package-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module-problem-under-vscode-only)
- [Java 8 to Kava 11 migration issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68771253/java-8-to-kava-11-migration-issue)
- [Specific question concerning "The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64870172/specific-question-concerning-the-package-org-w3c-dom-is-accessible-from-more-th)
- [Package is accessible from more than one module in JDK 11 Module system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56353171/package-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module-in-jdk-11-module-system)
- [Java build issues - Java 8 to Java 11 migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70743912/java-build-issues-java-8-to-java-11-migration)
- [how to solve javax.xml.namespace is accessible from more than one module with jdk11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62286414/how-to-solve-javax-xml-namespace-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module-with-jd)
- [The package org.openqa.selenium is accessible from more than one module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834695/the-package-org-openqa-selenium-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module)

Comment: What is the command line?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn *If* there is a way to see it: i don't know it.

Comment: What libraries/dependencies do you have in your project?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn While file or folder would i look at the find libraries? Which file or folder would i look at to find dependencies?

Comment: Anything that adds something to those packages.

Comment: What would be an example of **where** something would add anything to a package? Which file would you like me to dump the contents of? Which folder would you like me to dump to contents of?

Comment: Perhaps `build.xml`? I think that's an Ant file, which is a dependency management/build tool for Java (though I have no experience with it).

Comment: @Slaw The `build.xml` referenced a file inside the folder `nbproject`. I deleted `build.xml` and the folder `nbproject` (see edited question above) and the errors still happen.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean delete that file. I was answering [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72807971/how-to-make-a-package-not-accessible-from-a-module-i-e-how-to-remove-a-package#comment128601721_72807971) towards @JohannesKuhn.

Comment: @Slaw Well, it didn't break anything. It may have been leftover from Eclipse in 2005.

Comment: Might `WebRoot/WEB-INF/lib` be relevant? How about `WebRoot/META-INF`?

Comment: Yes. What libraries are in there? Names help, opening them with a zip program is better.

Comment: How do i know what libraries are in where? Which folder would you like a screenshot of? Which file would you like a screenshot of? The folder structure is in the question.

Comment: WebRoot/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Added the list of files in the `WebRoot/WEB-INF/lib` folder to the question.

Comment: In short, you get that error if a jar on the classpath has classes in the same package as some module - I guess, from the jar file names, that `dom.jar` contains classes in `org.w3c.dom`, `jaxp-api` - `javax.xml.parsers`... Just open the files as zip archive, and look if they contain one of the reported package names as folder (with `.` treated as path separator).